# Skip the method dom->find() if its fails

Tags: perl, logic

I am using Mojo::DOM for parsing HTML content.The issue i am facing is the program terminate if the function `dom->find()` fails,Its showing a error `cannot locate object error` . how can i skip the error and continue the execution of the program. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic way to do this is :

```
eval{ $dom->find('arg'); };
warn "eval had returned this error : [$@]\n" if $@;
```

Or with [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny) :

```
try {
    $dom->find('arg');
} catch {
    warn "caught error: $_"; # not $@
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know `$dom` is an object but don't know if it has the method you want, use `can`:

```
if($dom->can('find')) {
    # do something with $dom->find('arg');
}
```

This approach is useful for modules like URI which return different subclasses (with different methods) depending on the constructor arguments.